# How to use docker as a container on my system

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, tensorflow2.0

using Ubuntu 18.04.

Is it possible to use docker to simply "clone" my system and use all my installed libraries?

All i am trying to do is start using docker images for image processing.
I have Tensorflow 2.0-gpu installed on my system without any containers/virtual enviroments.
And I would like to just "Make a copy" of the current system and all its working libraries, So that if i update some dependencies, or try to upgrade keras/tensorflow or any other package and get some weird errors, I do NOT have to try and figure out what went wrong and can just fall back and create a new, fresh docker image from my base system.

All docker image files I have seen and tutorials always start this way: FROM "Some os/python version/..." , which I do not really want, I would like to just use FROM "this os with all its installed stuff".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to break it to you but short answer is **no**.

Longer one is that docker not a virtualization the way as any virtual machine works, but more like sharing host OS for running separated sets of processes (isolated by memory and rest of the stuff).

Meaning it uses host OS handlers to write into drive and to do calls into memory and etc. Docker doesn't do virtual hardware for container as virtual machine soft does. Thus you can't clone your OS into it.

And because Docker uses host OS for doing stuff - it is actually saves CPU resources on not doing OS logic in each container. - that is why it does performance gain comparing to classic VMs.

That is why for production purposes it definitely worth it just building image from the most empty (ubuntu) image - you never need image editing tool in production. So if you need to scale up one day you never going to spend more memory than your soft require (like in kubernets you can automatically scale up and down amount of docker containers basing on utilization metrics, but that is ultimate goal).

But plenty of VM software packages providing logic of cloning physical pc into image, so you if you need it you can utilize that.